# Esperar que se termine un servicio para continuar con otro AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promesas

Quisiera saber como hacer para esperar que se termine la ejecución de un servicio antes de que otro se ejecute, esto es porque lo que me devuelve el primer servicio es necesario para la ejecución del 2do.
Aqui mi servicio y mi controlador.

**configSrv.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('form.configSrv', []);

    app.factory('configSrv', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q) {

    var self = {

    config: {},

      load_config:function(){

        var d = $q.defer();

        $http.get('config.json')
            .then(function(resp){

                self.config = resp;
                d.resolve();
            })
            .catch(function(){
                d.reject();
                console.error("No se pudo cargar el archivo de configuracion :(");
            });

        return d.promise;

    }

    };

    return self;
    }]);
```

**Y mi controlador:**

```
    var app = angular.module('form.formCtrl', ['banecform.configSrv']);

    app.controller('formCtrl',
        ['$scope', 'sdmLogin', 'sdmQuery', 'sdmHandle', 'sdmCreate', 'sdmLogOut', 'sdmUploadFile', 'configSrv',
    function ($scope, sdmLogin, configSrv) {     
         configSrv.load_config().then(function() {
                $scope.config = configSrv.config;
    });

    sdmLogin.sdmLogin($scope.config.data.user, $scope.config.data.password).then(function () {
            $scope.loginToken = sdmLogin.login_token;
            });
    }]); // Fin de Ctrl
```

Como se observa en el código, mi intensión es que se ejecuten secuencialmente.
He probando anidandolos, pero luego eso me crea complicaciones ya que necesito hacer un logout cuando todo (otros servicios) hayan terminado y el servicio de logout se ejecuta antes de tiempo.

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Tal vez usando setTimeout setTimeout(function(){ //Code }, 50);